# Trouble with Parsoid and Visual Editor for Mediawiki

Tags: php, curl, mediawiki, visual-editor, parsoid

- Mediawiki Version **1.27**
- Visual Editor Version **1.27**
- Parsoid Version **latest in repository**

So I have several web servers running on an Ubuntu VM. The hostname is "atocha". I have Apache running on port 8000. Under this I have a Mediawiki instance. The mediawiki instance is not private.

I installed Parsoid and it is running on port 8142.

I can access my mediawiki instance by going do "http://atocha:8000/mediawiki/index.php"

I can curl the Mediawiki api just fine. "http://atocha:8000/mediawiki/api.php"

However when I try to edit the pages using Visual Editor I receive the following error **"Error loading from server: 404: docserver-http: HTTP 404. Would you like to retry?"** that pops up in a display. No error is thrown in Apache.

Here is my parsoid local settings.js file

```
'use strict';

exports.setup = function(parsoidConfig) {
    parsoidConfig.setMwApi({ 
        uri: 'http://atocha:8000/mediawiki/api.php', 
        domain: 'atocha',
        prefix: 'atocha'
    });
    parsoidConfig.useSelser = true;
};
```

Here is the pertinent LocalSettings.php section:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor');
// Enable by default for everybody
$wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;
// Don't allow users to disable it
$wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';

$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
        // URL to the Parsoid instance
        // Use port 8142 if you use the Debian package
        'url' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8142'
);
```

If I try to use parsoid like this in a browser:

```
http://atocha:8142/localhost/v3/page/Javadoc_Basics
```

I get this error:

```
Did not find page revisions for V3/page/Javadoc_Basics
```

If I try parsoid like this however:

```
http://atocha:8142/localhost:8000/v3/page/Javadoc_Basics
```

I get this:

```
Cannot GET /atocha:8000/v3/page/Javadoc_Basics
```

Anyone have an idea about what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much failure I was able to get parsoid and visual editor working.

Here is how I did it:

1. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Developer_Setup
2. Follow Option 2 for developer setup.
3. Run the tests
4. Change the config.yaml file for mediawiki settings and changed port number
5. Create UpStart job
6. Enjoy

Comment: serverPort to be more specific and don't forget to run service parsoid restart